# Git права на создаваемые файлы папки в дэбиане

Tags: права, git, linux

Суть проблемы в том, что когда один пользователь `git` создает в проекте папку в ней какие то файлы коментит и далее пушит все это на сервер на сервере появляются объекты гита с правами `r--r--r--` и папки с `rwxr-xr-x` `group` и `owner` проставляются верные именно того пользователя который пушил, а вот права не верные.
В `/home/username/.profile` указано `umask 022`

Как результат другие пользователи не могут делать `push` у них выводится ошибка об отсутствие прав.

Как правильно выставить `umask` чтобы права на файлы были `rw-rw-r-` и на папки `rwxrwxr-x`

Comment: такого быть не должно, если вы делаете push в bare репозиторий.

Comment: сами объекты в репозитории имеют 0444 права, вам нужно проверить, почему пользователю репозитария не доступно переписывать свои r/o файлы, проверьте  настройки безопасности системы, задайте вопрос на руткод.

Answer (score 1):

При создании нового разделяемого репозитория следует использовать ключ `--shared=group`:

```
[root@host repos]# groupadd <new_repo_group>
[root@host repos]# usermod -a -G <new_repo_group> <user1>
[root@host repos]# usermod -a -G <new_repo_group> <user2>
...
[root@host repos]# mkdir -p <new_repo>.git
[root@host repos]# chown :<new_repo_group> <new_repo>.git
[root@host repos]# chmod ug+ws <new_repo>.git
[root@host repos]# cd <new_repo>.git
[root@host <new_repo>.git]# git init --bare --shared=group
[root@host <new_repo>.git]# ls -l
total 32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root <new_repo_group>   23 Nov 23 12:06 HEAD
drwxrwsr-x 2 root <new_repo_group> 4096 Nov 23 12:06 branches
-rwxrw-r-- 1 root <new_repo_group>  126 Nov 23 12:06 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root <new_repo_group>   73 Nov 23 12:06 description
drwxrwsr-x 2 root <new_repo_group> 4096 Nov 23 12:06 hooks
drwxrwsr-x 2 root <new_repo_group> 4096 Nov 23 12:06 info
drwxrwsr-x 4 root <new_repo_group> 4096 Nov 23 12:06 objects
drwxrwsr-x 4 root <new_repo_group> 4096 Nov 23 12:06 refs
[root@rhyme <new_repo>.git]# _
```

Собственно, уже существующий репозиторий можно преобразовать в разделяемый путем выдачи соответствующих прав на файлы и каталоги внутри БД репозитория (каталог репозитория для bare-репозиториев или .git/ для обычных) и установления `core.sharedrepository` = 1 в конфигурационном файле `config`.

umask при этом может влиять (см. [man git-init](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html)), но, как правило, лучше на umask не полагаться.